# Python __doc__ behavior 2.6 vs 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, lambda, python-2.6

If I have the following code:

```
def foo(x, y):
    return x * y

t1 = lambda a, b: foo(x=a, y=b)
print t1.__doc__
```

Output in 2.6:

```
x
```

Output in 2.7:

```
None
```

Though the behavior in 2.7 looks accurate, I am not able to find a bug or change request for this changed behavior. Can someone throw more lights or link me to the change request for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was [Python issue 8164](https://bugs.python.org/issue8164). String constants used by a lambda's code were incorrectly getting interpreted as docstrings. This was [fixed](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/0dee9c1b5cba45c2a6c0320021f88397c559312e) by making `None` the first constant in a lambda's code.

Comment: @wim: The `x` for the keyword argument is stored as a string.

Comment: Yeah, I get it, but I don't think it's a "string constant".  Sorry, it was a rhetorical question  :)

Comment: Thank You for the response. Makes perfect sense.